# grep regex for strings starting with two characters of certain length

Tags: regex, grep

I want to display a string starting with `a7` of length 32 alphanumeric characters. I have tried various regexes which I would expect to work but they don't seem to. This is using `grep` on Ubuntu.

If i just use `grep <file> -e 'a9'` it will show the string, but when trying to filter it based on the first characters being `a7` and length of 32 using `grep <file> -e '/a7.{32}$'` nothing is returned. Is there something wrong with this expression making it not work?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep -e` specifies `BRE` and you will need to add backslash before
`{` and `}` as: `grep -e 'a7.\{32\}' file`.

Comment: This is so unclear, please provide some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length is 32, then you only want **30** more chars, not **32**:

```
grep <file> -e '/a7\w\{30\}$'
```

I changed the dot to `\w` (word char) because you said you want alphanumeric characters. To be stricter, use `'/a7[a-zA-Z0-9]\{30\}$'` instead of `\w`, which includes the underscore character (it may not matter to you though).

Also, you have to escape the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

grep, a standard UNIX utility, uses Basic Regular Expression (BRE) apart from normal strings as a search pattern. In BRE, meta-characters like: `'{'`,`'}'`,`'('`,`')'`,`'|'`,`'+'`,`'?'` loose their meaning and are treated as normal characters of string. So, they need to be escaped if they are treated as special characters.

```
grep <file> -e "a7.\{30\}"
```

If you do not want to add backslash to escape meta-characters, you could use egrep which treats the pattern as an extended regular expression.

```
egrep "a7.{30}" <file>
```